# popup centered on page despite scrolling

Tags: css, css-position

i was wondering if you could help me. I have various buttons on my site which displays a popup when clicked on. I need the popup to be displayed in the middle of the page whether i click a button at the top of the page or the bottom. The CSS code i use for the popup is

```
.popupheading{ font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#ff0000}
.popupmsg{
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:10px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcf5f4',   endColorstr='#fddad8',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px #e0e0e0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px #e0e0e0;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #f0cac8;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#333;
}
```

I have tried using `margin-left` and `margin-top` and using percentage of the screen but that has not worked.
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Changing position to fixed from absolute.

'Absolute' positions the div relative to its normal position, whereas 'fixed' will position it relative to the browser.

try this:

```
.popupheading{ font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#ff0000}
.popupmsg{
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
z-index: 100;
height: 400px;
margin-top: -200px;
margin-left: -300px;
width:600px;
padding:20px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcf5f4',   endColorstr='#fddad8',GradientType=0 );
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px #e0e0e0;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px #e0e0e0;
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px #e0e0e0;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #f0cac8;
text-align:center;
font-size:13px;
color:#333;
}
```

Comment: The fixed position does not work at all and no popup appears :(